# How to append 3 elements from ajax/json on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem with json response and part appending data to html.

My json have now 15 elements, but will have more in future.

Now, I'm appending every elements with ajax from json file.

I want to append 3 elements from JSON on click.

I tried to use for loop instead $.each onclick, but I haven't good effect.

My code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var $itemsList = $("#items-list");

        $.ajax({
        url: 'items.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(items){
            $("#more-items").on('click', function() {
                $.each(items, function(i, item) {

                    /*INCLDE ITEM BOXES*/
                    $itemsList.append(
                        '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">' +
                            '<a href="#'+ item.id +'" class="item-link" data-toggle="modal">' +
                                '<div class="item-hover">' +
                                    '<div class="item-hover-content">' +
                                        '<i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<img src="'+ item.thumbnailUrl +'" class="img-responsive" alt="">' +
                            '</a>' +
                            '<div class="item-caption">' +
                                '<p class="text-muted">'+item.caption+'</p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
                    );

                    /*INCLUDE ITEM MODALS*/
                    $('body').after().append(
                        '<div class="item-modal modal fade" id="'+item.id+'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">'+
                            '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                '<div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">'+
                                    '<div class="lr">'+
                                        '<div class="rl">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="container">'+
                                    '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">'+
                                            '<div class="modal-body">'+
                                                '<h3>'+item.title+'</h3>'+
                                                '<p class="item-intro text-muted">'+item.subtitle+'</p>'+
                                                '<img class="img-responsive img-centered" src="'+item.imgUrl+'" alt="">'+
                                                '<a class="btn btn-info item-link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="'+item.link+'"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Zobacz online</a>'+
                                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Zamknij</button>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'
                    );
                });
            });
        }
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log('items import done!');
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });

});
```

Thanks everyone for any advice and examples.

Comment: not related, but you have a success and done function, .success is deprecated in favor of .done

Comment: The first issue I see is that you have this: "$("#more-items").on('click', function() {" Which is adding an event handler inside your ajax success function. I don't see how anything is being appended. You need to move your event handling declarations out of this method completely.... I would recommend that you do your coding server side. Pass your server side code the index of the next item you want. Let it generate the json file containing only the next 3 items. Then you can append all items to the page and it will only add 3. you can use a var to track the next index.